# How to interpret clusters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I tried to use k-means to cluster users per category of used Applications(exp: Communication, games).
I obtaine 4 clusters as below:[image]

How can i interpret clusters ? I tried to obtain for example cluster 1 use more communication and social media than cluster 3.
Is there a method to visualize each cluster separately?

Answer (score 1):

You statement is...How can i interpret clusters?  I interpret that as you want to print out the details of the clusters.  Is that right?  You didn't post any sample code here, but check out the code below, which is quite dynamic (it automatically imports stock data from Yahoo Finance).  I'll give you some setup steps below, and then address, what I thin is your question, right at the end, below the term 'Results:'.

```
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans 
import pandas_datareader as dr
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


start = '2019-1-1'
end = '2020-1-1'

tickers = ['AXP','AAPL','BA','CAT','CSCO','CVX','XOM','GS','HD','IBM','INTC','JNJ','KO','JPM','MCD',    'MMM',  'MRK',  'MSFT', 'NKE','PFE','PG','TRV','UNH','RTX','VZ','V','WBA','WMT','DIS','DOW']
prices_list = []
for ticker in tickers:
    try:
        prices = dr.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',start)['Adj Close']
        prices = pd.DataFrame(prices)
        prices.columns = [ticker]
        prices_list.append(prices)
    except:
        pass
    prices_df = pd.concat(prices_list,axis=1)
prices_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
prices_df.head()


#Calculate average annual percentage return and volatilities over a theoretical one year period
returns = prices_df.pct_change().mean() * 252
returns = pd.DataFrame(returns)
returns.columns = ['Returns']
returns['Volatility'] = prices_df.pct_change().std() * sqrt(252)
#format the data as a numpy array to feed into the K-Means algorithm
data = np.asarray([np.asarray(returns['Returns']),np.asarray(returns['Volatility'])]).T
X = data
distorsions = []
for k in range(2, 20):
    k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
    k_means.fit(X)
    distorsions.append(k_means.inertia_)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(range(2, 20), distorsions)
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('Elbow curve')
```

[image]

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
kmeans.fit(X)

# 3D Plot of KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
km.fit(X)
km.predict(X)
labels = km.labels_#Plotting
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(7,7))
ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0, 0, 0.95, 1], elev=48, azim=134)
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], 
          c=labels.astype(np.float), edgecolor="k", s=50)
ax.set_xlabel("X-axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Y-axis")
ax.set_zlabel("Z-axis")
plt.title("K Means", fontsize=14)
```

[image]

```
# Plot KMeans with Centroids
#K-Means
returns = prices_df.pct_change().mean() * 252
returns = pd.DataFrame(returns)
returns.columns = ['Returns']
returns['Volatility'] = prices_df.pct_change().std() * sqrt(252)
#format the data as a numpy array to feed into the K-Means algorithm
data = np.asarray([np.asarray(returns['Returns']),np.asarray(returns['Volatility'])]).T
X = data

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5).fit(X)
labels = kmeans.predict(X)
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1],c=labels)
plt.scatter(centers[:,0],centers[:,1],c='red',s=100,marker='x')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# KMeans with annotations
# Hierarchial Clustering of Stocks
#labels = prices_df.columns.tolist()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.1)
plt.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], c=kmeans.labels_, cmap='rainbow') 

for label, x, y in zip(labels, data[:, 0], data[:, 1]):
    plt.annotate(
        label,
        xy=(x, y), xytext=(-20, 20),
        textcoords='offset points', ha='right', va='bottom',
        bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.5', fc='red', alpha=0.5),
        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# List of tickers and cluter IDs
details = [(name,cluster) for name, cluster in zip(returns.index,labels)]
for detail in details:
    print(detail)
```

Results:

```
('AXP', 0)
('AAPL', 3)
('BA', 4)
('CAT', 0)
('CSCO', 1)
('CVX', 1)
('XOM', 1)
('GS', 0)
('HD', 2)
('IBM', 1)
('INTC', 0)
('JNJ', 2)
('KO', 1)
('JPM', 0)
('MCD', 2)
('MMM', 1)
('MRK', 1)
('MSFT', 3)
('NKE', 0)
('PFE', 1)
('PG', 2)
('TRV', 2)
('UNH', 2)
('RTX', 2)
('VZ', 1)
('V', 2)
('WBA', 1)
('WMT', 2)
('DIS', 0)
('DOW', 0)
```

See the link below for more info.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Clustering%20-%20Historical%20Stock%20Prices.ipynb